# Count occurrences of a string in an array using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have an array which looks like this:

```
[
  {pax_type: 'ADT', traveller_id: 1},
  {pax_type: 'ADT', traveller_id: 2},
  {pax_type: 'ADT', traveller_id: 3},
  {pax_type: 'CHD', traveller_id: 4},
  {pax_type: 'CHD', traveller_id: 5},
  {pax_type: 'INF', traveller_id: 6}
]
```

How can I count the number of times 'ADT' appeared in this array in JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `.filter()`:

```js
const input = [
  {pax_type: 'ADT', traveller_id: 1},
  {pax_type: 'ADT', traveller_id: 2},
  {pax_type: 'ADT', traveller_id: 3},
  {pax_type: 'CHD', traveller_id: 4},
  {pax_type: 'CHD', traveller_id: 5},
  {pax_type: 'INF', traveller_id: 6}
];

const output = input.filter((e) => e.pax_type === 'ADT').length;
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce` as

```
var count = inputs.reduce((counter, {pax_type}) => pax_type == "ADT" ? counter + 1 : counter, 0);
```

```js
var inputs = [
  {pax_type: 'ADT', traveller_id: 1},
  {pax_type: 'ADT', traveller_id: 2},
  {pax_type: 'ADT', traveller_id: 3},
  {pax_type: 'CHD', traveller_id: 4},
  {pax_type: 'CHD', traveller_id: 5},
  {pax_type: 'INF', traveller_id: 6}
]

var count = inputs.reduce((counter, {pax_type}) => pax_type == "ADT" ? counter + 1 : counter, 0);
console.log(count)
```